# does (hash) mean anything as a function parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

```
var newFieldShow = function(hash) {
  hash.w.fadeIn("2000");
};
```

I see this in some [code](http://www.ianlewis.org/en/ok-cancel-buttons-with-jqmodal) I have retrieved from online. I've never seen hash mentioned.. I am trying to determine if it has something to do with hashing, or if it's just an event reference like `function(event)` which I'm used to seeing, and curious as to why it is being used here.

Comment: Formal parameters to functions are very similar to variables. It's just a name that references whatever argument was passed to the function. Nearly the same as if you did `var hash = arguments[0];`, where `arguments` is a collection representing all the arguments passed when the function was invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of a variable is just a hint at what the function expects as input, but there is no real "type hinting" in Javascript that would enforce any such policy.

Hash/object are used interchangeably in Javascript because object members can also be accessed in a fashion that is similar to the syntax of how you would access entries in a hash table in other languages.

```
hash.w
```

is equivalent to

```
hash["w"]
```

The latter is a syntax common in languages such as Python or Ruby (in fact the class implementing this behavior is called "Hash" in Ruby).

So the word "hash" does not refer to a cryptographic hash or a hash function but rather to the functionality of a hash table.

Objects are often referred to as "Hashes" in Javascript if they are merely a collection of key/value pairs but don't implement any functions, e.g.

```
hash = {
    a: 5,
    b: "string",
    c: 7
}
```

opposed to

```
object = {
    member_a: 5,
    member_b: "string",
    do_this: function() { ... },
    do_that: function() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In this context, `hash` is just the name given to a function parameter and has no special meaning beyond "the internal name (within the function) of the first parameter passed to the function named `newFieldShow`".  The name "hash" is not a reserved name in Javascript.

---

In general programming, the term `hash` is often short for an object or thing with "hash-table like" capabilities.  A hash table provides fast lookup of a piece of data when given a key.  Javascript has similar types of capabilities in it's object type.

```
obj["foo"] = "One fine day";
console.log(obj["foo"]);    // outputs 'One fine day'.
```

---

In the specific case you asked about, all we can see from the couple lines of code you have included is that:

1. 'hash' is an object that has a 'w' property.
2. The value of the `w` property is an object with a method `.fadeIn()`.
3. Since `fadeIn()` is a relatively well known jQuery method, `hash.w` is probably a jQuery object.

Answer (score 5):

If someone sent me this code I would say that **hash** is an object with a property named w that looks to be a jQuery object (because of the fadeIn method).

**hash** could mean anything.  Thus, the need to properly name variables (and function parameters) that make sense.